# Deduping a list of tuples, but keeping collisions as a list

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, tuples

I am new to F# and functional languages in general. I'm having a hard time coming up with a recursive way to de-dupe a list of tuples in the following way:

```
 [("Apple", "500");
  ("Orange", "123");
  ("Pineapple", "300");
  ("Apple", "200");
  ("Apple", "100");
  ("Orange", "234");
  ("Cucumber", "900");]

  --becomes-->

  [("Apple", ["500", "200", "100"]);
  ("Orange", ["123", "234"]);
  ("Pineapple", ["300"]);
  ("Cucumber", ["900"]);]
```

Basically i want something like a map to a list. Explanations appreciated, as I am still having a hard time reading functional code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grouping can be performed using [`Seq.groupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.groupby%5B't%2C'key%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Running `Seq.groupBy fst input` yields:

```
seq
  [("Apple", seq [("Apple", "500"); ("Apple", "200"); ("Apple", "100")]);
   ("Orange", seq [("Orange", "123"); ("Orange", "234")]);
   ("Pineapple", seq [("Pineapple", "300")]);
   ("Cucumber", seq [("Cucumber", "900")])]
```

This is close, but not quite what you want because the second items of the resulting tuple contain the full input object, whereas your example indicates you want to pull out the second item from the list. You can get the second item from a tuple using [`snd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples), and since you have a sequence of tuples from which you wish to pull the second element, you can use [`Seq.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.map%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
let grouped = Seq.groupBy fst input
              |> Seq.map (fun (a, b) -> (a, Seq.map snd b))

printfn "%A" grouped

// yields...
seq
  [("Apple", seq ["500"; "200"; "100"]); ("Orange", seq ["123"; "234"]);
   ("Pineapple", seq ["300"]); ("Cucumber", seq ["900"])]
```

Comment: In newer versions of F#, the various functions in various container types are homogenized. So, instead of using ``Seq.groupBy``, a simple 1 liner: ``List.groupBy fst input`` would do.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a List.fold to accomplish your goal:

```
let input = 
    [
        ("Apple", "500");
        ("Orange", "123");
        ("Pineapple", "300");
        ("Apple", "200");
        ("Apple", "100");
        ("Orange", "234");
        ("Cucumber", "900");
    ]

let output =
    List.fold (fun (acc : Map<string,string list>) (k,v) ->
        match Map.tryFind k acc with
        | Some x -> Map.add k (v :: x) acc
        | None -> Map.add k [v] acc
    ) Map.empty input
    // If you want a list instead of a map in the end, uncomment the next line.
    // |> Map.toList
```

which yields:

> val output : Map =
>     map
>       [("Apple", ["100"; "200"; "500"]); ("Cucumber", ["900"]);
>        ("Orange", ["234"; "123"]); ("Pineapple", ["300"])]

While not as to the point as the `groupBy` version, the `fold` is your Swiss army knife for many occasions and worth being used to.

And - while there are those nice ready made functions like `fold` coming for free with F#, if you want a recursive definition, you can write your own fold as a learning exercise. It could look like this and should work with the same lambda I used above.

```
let rec myFold folder acc values =
    match values with
    | [] -> acc
    | (x::xs) -> myFold folder (folder acc x) xs
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use the `Seq.groupBy` function designed for this purpose, a recursive way of grouping would be an immutable data structure to hold the groupings, like [Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5B%27key,%27value%5D-class-%5Bfsharp%5D)<*,*>. It will produce the elements in sorted order when eventually enumerated. If the original order shall be preserved, a mutable data structure, e.g. [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2)<*,*>, may be considered functional enough, as long as it is kept local to a function.

```
let groupByFst input =
    let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
    let rec aux = function
    | [] -> [ for KeyValue(k, vs) in d -> k, List.rev vs ]
    | (k, v)::tail ->
        match d.TryGetValue k with
        | true, vs -> d.[k] <- v::vs
        | _ -> d.Add(k, [v])
        aux tail
    aux input
// val groupByFst : input:('a * 'b) list -> ('a * 'b list) list when 'a : equality

[ "Apple", "500"
  "Orange", "123"
  "Pineapple", "300"
  "Apple", "200"
  "Apple", "100"
  "Orange", "234"
  "Cucumber", "900"]
|> groupByFst
// val it : (string * string list) list =
//   [("Apple", ["500"; "200"; "100"]); ("Orange", ["123"; "234"]);
//    ("Pineapple", ["300"]); ("Cucumber", ["900"])]
```